# Applybinding to entire dom or to each individual element which needs it?

Tags: javascript, coding-style, knockout.js

New to Knockout. What is more maintainable and regarded as a better coding practice?

A) Should i create 1 large viewmodel and apply that binding to the entire dom? 
B) Should i create many models and apply their binding to each element which needs that model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create one master view model that creates other view models within it then do something like this once you've bound the master view model to the  or whatever you're binding to.

```
<body id="bind-the-master-to-me">
    <!-- ko with: childViewModelA -->
    <div data-bind="visible: shouldIBeVisible">...</div>
    <!-- /ko -->

    <!-- ko with: childViewModelB -->
    <div data-bind="foreach: somePropOfB">...</div>
    <!-- /ko -->
</body>
```

Hope that helps